# View with rotation property get cuts off

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, cardview

- I have to create three `CardView` like structure as shown in the below image. For that, I am currently using
  `Constraintlayout` but facing multiple issues i.e, clipping issue.
- There is no usecase of swipe animation or anything like that.
- Is there anything that I am missing here.Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_one"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:rotation="-20"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_25"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8"
                            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_1"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_one"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/top_colored_gradient_dark"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12">

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_one"
                                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/blue_social" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/img_one"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                                    android:textColor="#313131"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp"
                                    tools:text="Title Here" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_name"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/light_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_11sp"
                                    tools:text="Date" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_second"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_2"
                            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_15"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/card_third"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_one"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_two"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/top_colored_gradient_dark"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12">

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_two"
                                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/blue_social" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_name_two"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/img_two"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                                    android:textColor="#313131"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp"
                                    tools:text="Title Here" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_date_two"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_name_two"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/light_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_11sp"
                                    tools:text="Date" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_third"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_1"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
                            android:rotation="20"
                            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_second"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_third"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/top_colored_gradient_dark"
                                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12">

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_third"
                                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/blue_social" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_name_third"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/img_third"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                                    android:textColor="#313131"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp"
                                    tools:text="Title Here" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_date_third"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_name_third"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/light_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_11sp"
                                    tools:text="Date" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "clipping issue"?

Comment: It gets cut off whenever I use rotation property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout instead of constraint to stack Views like in the Image.